# how do i add a program to path with python?

Tags: python, github

i have a program that is going to install a folder, and i want that folder to be added to path when it is downloaded.

this was my code.

```
import os
import requests
import zipfile
import shutil

def download_file(url, save_path):
    # Download the file from the URL
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)

def extract_zip(zip_path, extract_path):
    # Extract the contents of the ZIP file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(extract_path)

def add_to_path(directory):
    # Add the directory containing "insulter.exe" to the PATH environment variable
    insulter_directory = os.path.join(directory, "Insult-CLI-build")
    os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + insulter_directory

def main():
    # URL of the file to download
    file_url = 'https://github.com/my2religion2is2sillyism2imma2sillybilly/Insult-CLI/archive/refs/heads/build.zip'

    # Directory where the file will be saved and extracted
    current_directory = os.getcwd()

    # Download the file
    file_name = file_url.split('/')[-1]
    save_path = os.path.join(current_directory, file_name)
    download_file(file_url, save_path)

    # Extract the file 
    if file_name.endswith('.zip'):
        extract_zip(save_path, current_directory)

    # Add the extracted directory to the PATH
    add_to_path(current_directory)

    print("File downloaded and added to PATH successfully!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

it said it was succesfully added to path, but all it did was install and unzip the folder.

Comment: It did add to PATH, but for the running process only. If you need to modify the global system PATH, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121795/programmatically-modifiy-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def add_to_path(directory):
variable
    insulter_directory = os.path.join(directory, "Insult-CLI-build")
    os.environ['PATH'] = insulter_directory + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
```

Additionally, make sure that the directory structure after extraction matches your expectations and that the insult.exe file actually exists in the Insult-CLI-build directory.